# How to do filter in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I'm having a table with `Manager` details with the  following fields,

```
 Name,   ID
```

and a child table `Appoinments` it will contain the following fields,

```
Manager ID , Date, Appoinment Details.
```

Now i need to get the maneger details from the Maneger table , those who are having no appoinment on today.

Im new to SQl . Please help me to write the Query

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 3):

Note I have assumed that you are using SQL Server.

```
select m.*
  from manager m
 where not exists (select *
                     from appointments a
                    where m.id = a.manager_id
                      and a.date >= datediff(d,0,getdate())
                      and a.date <  datediff(d,-1,getdate()));
```

Note:
datediff(d,0,getdate()) = Today
datediff(d,-1,getdate()) = Tomorrow

Comment: How to do this using join??

Comment: Not sure why you would want to do it with a join where the more elegant exists syntax would work, but you could left join manager to appointments with filters as per @RichardTheKiwi's answer and test for null in appointments

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from manager m
where not exists
(
    select 1
    from appointments a
    where a.manager = m.manager
    and a.date = today (whatever today in your SQL is)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are correct, this is a join version:

```
SELECT M.Name, M.ID
FROM manager M LEFT JOIN appointments A ON M.id = A.manager_id
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, A.date)) != DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY M.Name, M.ID;
```